NPM project importing sister project as file package won't run install script for sister project
I have a monorepo with two projects:
> A
  - src/ etc....
  - package.json
> B
  - src/ etc...
  - package.json

And B lists A as a dependency (file:../A).
When running npm i in B, I noticed that preinstall and postinstall are triggered for A, but not install. Is this intended behavior or is this likely a bug (or other configuration issue)? The docs don't speak much about this functionality.

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question and/or setup, but I'm able to get the install script to run.
Given this structure:
.
├── a/
│   └── package.json
└── b/
    └── package.json

While using npm v10.5.0 and not creating workspaces with npm init -w or a workspaces field in a root package.json file I am able to get the install script from dependency a to run.
package.json for a
{
    "name": "a",
    "scripts": {
        "preinstall": "touch preinstall.txt",
        "postinstall": "touch postinstall.txt",
        "install": "touch install.txt"
    }
}

package.json for b
{
    "name": "b",
    "dependencies": {
        "a": "file:../a"
    }
}

Now inside of b/ run npm i. You will see the following files created:

a/preinstall.txt
a/install.txt
a/postinstall.txt

Similarly, if you do scaffold the monorepo with npm init -w a and npm init -w b you get the same results (except you will have a root package.json file in this case).

Apparently, install as a script is not the same as the install that is run with npm install. When running npm i in B, it does npm run install on A but not npm install - having the script for install alias to npm install did it for me. Thanks!

Confusing, I know. The install script for a package is a lifecycle hook to perform tasking when the package is installed via the npm install command. If you simply want all your monorepo workspaces to install their dependencies with one npm install command you can use the workspaces field from the root package.json and then run the install command from the root.

Yes most likely it is expected behavior, Though you are using monorepo you got different projects there, which most likely don't have any relation of dependencies as both have different package.json
If you are doing npm i for project A it should not affect package.json of B and vise versa
I also woild like to here more about what do you expect and the problem if you can share
